# Specify two icon sizes in iPhone4/iPad app

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-4

The iPad and iPhone4 both are armv7 (not 6), and I'm curious to know how to specify two separate icon sizes given that the target architecture is exactly the same.  Specifying two in a typical universal app is simple, however I'm not sure how to do this.  I can't find it in the documentation, although it may be!  (Sorry if it is; and I'm sorry if this was asked before!)

Thanks!

Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better more detailed [link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW1).

> Application Icons
>
> When specifying icon files using the
>   CFBundleIconFiles key, it is best to
>   omit the filename extensions of your
>   image files. If you include a filename
>   extension, you must explicitly add all
>   of your image files (including any
>   high-resolution variants) to the
>   array. ***When you omit the filename
>   extension, the system automatically
>   detects high-resolution variants of
>   your file using the base filename you
>   provide.***

Answer (score 3):

In order to specify two different sizes for the iPhone4 and iPad, refer to [iTunesConnect Developer Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf). It lists the image sizes you need in order to do so (both should be included in your binary).

What you're looking for is under the Requirements section beginning on page 6.

Hope this helps...